# Unexpected quantifier in regex in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, regex, microsoft-edge

I have a regex which finds any string between 2 `##`-characters:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(?<=\#\#)(.*?)(?=\#\#)');
var matchResult = searchString.match(regex);
```

E.g. a string

`"test bla bla ##TARGET## blablabla"` gives me `TARGET`, which is what I want.
It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox. However MS Edge gives me the error message:

**`Unexpected quantifier`**

How do I need to change the regex, that it also works for Microsoft Edge?
I tried escaping the `?` but that did not help. Which characters do I need to escape?

Comment: Edge doesn't support lookbehinds,

Comment: `var matchResult = searchString.match(/##(.*?)##/)[1];`. Matching a string between two strings with JavaScript regex is a very common issue and has been covered in many SO (and other) posts. A lookbehind is supported by ECMAScript 2018 compatible JS environments only.

Comment: Have you tried double escaping the hash symbols? Older IE had issues with this, not sure how it is now. `new RegExp('(?<=\\#\\#)(.*?)(?=\\#\\#)');`